Recoverable overcurrent protection of MOSFET using eFuse
I am looking into a way to improve over-current protection of an industrial device with switching contact output (based on PMV37ENEA MOSFET) that is rated for 1A / 30VDC load.
The PMV37ENEA is protected from short-circuit by the through-hole mounted ceramic fuse.
The problem is that once the fuse is activated, the device is bricked (fuse is not replaceable).
In order to mitigate this, I was planning to replace ceramic fuse with PTC resettable one, but there is no decent alternative that have low current deviation in industrial  temperature range (say, LittleFuse 471 Series has deviation +-10% and LittleFuse PolySwitch +-50%).
Thus I am looking something like eFuse to automatically detect over-current/short-circuit and protect PMV37ENEA by opening the circuit.
The problem is that existing eFuses that I have found (like ST STEF01) are meant to get the power for internal logic from power supply and has a minimum voltage 8V.
However, in my case power supply voltage comes from external source and could be any, i.e. less then 8V.
I tried to find eFuse which allows to power internal logic from separate external low voltage power, but haven't found.
So basically I am looking for suggestion on how to protect PMV37ENEA from over-current without using ceramic one-time fuse.
Thanks.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab

Have you checked the tolerance of that ceramic fuse? I'm pretty sure it's worse than the PTC.

What's wrong with something like this: https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps2640.pdf?ts=1713293194965&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fpower-management%252Fpower-switches%252Fefuse-hotswap-controllers%252Fproducts.html ?

Fuses and PTCs are usually there to keep your wiring from starting a fire in the event of catastrophic failure of a downstream device. If your load is continually tripping the existing overcurrent protection, then the problem is most constructively addressed at the load.

Or if you just want current limiting (not fuse functionality) this will operate down to 2.7 V: https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps1641.pdf?ts=1713293134786&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fpower-management%252Fpower-switches%252Fefuse-hotswap-controllers%252Fproducts.html

I don't see back-emf protection in your circuit so, please convince me you are trying to solve the right problem.

You could use a more advanced gate driver that includes overcurrent protection; I think some of Analog's ADuM series do, for instance. These just drive the MOSFET off regardless of input signal in an overcurrent event (and they typically can also send a fault signal to the control circuit for it to do whatever it needs to in response).

@Andyaka as stated in comments below the schematic, it is not the entire circuit. Schematic consists of several pages and would be not if I posted it as is.
That's why I have made a sketch that shows the main component and states the problem I want to solve.
Actual schematic contains protection against inrush currents, over-voltage, etc.

Partial circuits don't help on this occasion.

@JonathanS. yes, I did. We use LittleFuse 0471001.NRT1L and it has +-10% deviation across -50 to +125 degrees.

@Andyaka updated the schematic. Please let me know if more details are needed

@vir agree. That's why the original fuse can remain in the schematic.
However, additionally I would like to add over-current protection to avoid fuse burn and thus prolong the device lifetime (fuse is not replaceable)

@JohnD these are worth checking. However I would prefer eFuse that acts like simple fuse (i.e. two pins - in/out) and don't have any input voltage requirements. To power internal logic of eFuse I would prefer to have separate power pins that can be galvanic isolated from main power source of device.
However, I am not able to find anything similar (maybe eFuse is not even a correct term here)

@rostokus what function are those inductors marked 2A <-- they are really problematic in terms of generating back-emf

@Andyaka sorry, actually these are ferrite bead 600Ohm, 2A. Update the schematic

Ixys CPC1561B is almost an ideal fit, except the max temperate limit - only +85C
